# Vuejs - vuex lazy load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have a fairly large VueJS SPA, and I just wanted to load the vuex modules on certain routes, using the lazy load.

I was following this article to reproduce this - https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/

However this is giving me an error in vuex.

Folder structure

```
root
  |- store
  | |- modules
  | | |- auth.js
  | | |- module2.js
  | |- store.js
  |- app.js
```

auth.js

```
const state = {
    var1: {},
    var2: false
}

const mutations = {
    'MUTATION_1'(state, obj) {
        // logic
    }
}

const actions = {
    action1({commit}) {
       // logic
    }
}

const getters = {
    var1: state => state.var1,
    var2: state => state.var2
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

store.js -

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store();

import('./modules/auth.js').then(auth => {
    store.registerModule('/login', auth);
});

export default store;
```

app.js -

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from './store/store';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes/routes';

// vue-router config
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
});
```

error -

```
[vuex] unknown getter: var1
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
store.registerModule('/login', auth);
```

The above code registers the `auth` module with the namespace of `login` so in order to access its state, getters, mutations, and actions from the store you have to prefix all of those with the path `login/`. You got the error because you probably tried `store.getters.var1` when you should have called `store.getters['login/var1']`.

Answer (score 2):

Getter is called before the login module was loaded. This happens because `import()` is asynchronous function, and the module was registered sometime after computed watcher was created.
`return store.state.login && store.getters['login/var1']` inside component computed getter will subscribe your component to `store.state` changes first, then after login module loaded and registered `store.state` will change and trigger component computed getter and automatically subscribe to any `state.login` changes